# 301 redirect.htaccess on entire site EXCEPT for main domain url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I all, I've been searching a lot but I don't find an answer to my problem.

I have already made a .htaccess file that redirects all the different pages and files on my old domain (www.olddomain.com) to my new domain (www.newdomain/blog.com). I'm moving a blog to an e-commerce, that's why 301 to www.newdomain/blog.com.

However, I need to use the Change of Address Tool (Google Webmaster Tools) but I can't because www.olddomain.com must redirect to www.newdomain.com and now it is redirecting to www.newdomain/blog.com and Google don't let me change the address.

My .htaccess is working fine except for that, here it is

```
RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$

  RewriteRule (.*)$ http:/www.newdomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

BUT, I have not found any way to make an exception to redirect just www.olddomain.com must ---> www.newdomain.com

I have tried to make that exception in the following way:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$

  RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But nothing has worked...

Please, can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 RewriteEngine On
#redirect http://oldsite.com/ to http://newsite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http:/www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#redirect http://oldsite.com/pages to http://newsite.com/blog/pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http:/www.newdomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note the `^$` in pattern it matches `/` ie : `http://example.com/` or the directory the htaccess file is in.

Clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Finally got it: 

RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$

RewriteRule (.*)$ http:/www.newdomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

This worked! thanks!